# Google Pay в Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, google-pay

Хочу (странного) завести Google Pay (JS) в WebView в Android приложении. Если верить этому https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/support/faq?hl=ru

> For Android apps which use WebViews, you must invoke native Android Google Pay APIs. See Binding JavaScript code to Android code for examples.

то задача осуществима. Но когда пытаюсь сделать, то получаю:

```
PaymentRequest is not defined
```

Причем кнопочка Google Pay на странице рендерится, при клике проходит авторизация, а затем модалка с текстом "На стороне разработчика произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку позже.". В консоли соответственно ошибка об отсутствии PaymentRequest.

А если верить этому https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaymentRequest/canMakePayment, то Payment Request API в Android VebView нет.

Кому верить и как быть? Что конкретно надо сделать с WebView чтобы Google Pay заработал? Если я правильно понял ил этого https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview?hl=ru#BindingJavaScript, то надо отключить этот BindingJavaScript. У меня его и небыло включено... Или его надо как-то явно выпилить?

PS В браузере на десктопе платежная кнопка работает как надо.

Comment: Я конечно таким не занимался, делаю выводы по приведённой информации. Вам предлагается использовать `Google Pay API (java)` так же как в любых других приложениях (c `WebView` или без него). А для связи с `JS` реализовать `JavascriptInterface`, который перекинет вызов из `JS` в `java`-код и уже там вы обратитесь к API покупок.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, удалось ли найти решение ?

Answer (score 0):

Одним из возможных решений является использование

```
androidx.browser:browser:X.X.X
```

Полноценный браузер, встроенный в приложение, в котором есть доступ к gpay

Comment: для уточняющих вопросов место — в комментариях. когда ваша репутация достигнет 50, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к чужим сообщениям.